# .net core package restore failed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-1.1

## Package restore

Package restore failed in ASP.NET Core 1.1. 
Note: I am targeting following in my project.

> "frameworks": {
>       "net461": { }
>     },

Recently I upgraded my project from ASP.NET Core 1.0 to 1.1 and it worked fine on my old laptop until I switched the project to fresh new laptop, and installed visual studio 15. Here is the configuration of the VS 15.

[image]

I have also installed the required SDK as mentioned on this link 
https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2016/11/20/upgrading-from-net-core-1-0-t0-1-1-with-visual-studio-2015/

[image]

Now my `project.json` file looks likes this.

[image]

And `global.json` looks like this.

> {
>     "projects": [ "." ]
>   }

But as you can see the packages are not loading as expected. When I run `dotnet restore` from the package manager console I get something like this.

[image]

Any ideas ??

Comment: Try deleting all `project.json.lock` file, `bin`, and `obj` folders, and try restoring again.

Comment: @ignas tried that as well. But it still the same.

Comment: Can you hover mouse over these errors in `project.json` file? There should be a specific reason why it's failing to restore the packages. Can you share with us that reason?

Comment: What I usually do in such case:

1. Remove project.lock.json

2. Remove bin and obj manually

3. Restore projects

Answer (score 0):

***I fixed same issue when i add file***

If you see this error with adding some code file for example Controller, View etc.
Than one of reasons is CodeGeneration package failed when you try to add some file.

add nuget package which is

**Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design**